# How can I rewrite all urls to "/"?

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Server: Apache

I'm looking to rewrite my urls in the following way, and I can't figure out a way to get it to work.

```
http://website.com/index.html
```

I want it to redirect to:

```
http://website.com/
```

So basically I want to load index.html, but not display it in the url. I also don't want to give it another name. I'm not looking for **/index.html** to become **/index**

Additionally, I'm trying to have any GET data such as:

```
http://website.com/index.html?id=0&name="fred"
```

To rewrite to:

```
http://website.com/?id=0&name="fred".
```

If you have a solution that is not using .htaccess files that's fine as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.html(.*)$ /$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This will redirect any requests that start with `/index.html` to simply "`/`" and will preserve any arguments that come after `index.html`

Comment: The starting slash definitely SHOULD NOT be there.

Answer (score 1):

For a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.html
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [L,R=301]
```